# While showing a list of objects, should I retrieve a list of complete objects or just the necessary part of the objects

Tags: database, rest, http, https, flutter

I'm working on an travel app in flutter. There are 2 pages in the app.

One that shows the list of packages as below:
[image: List of packages]

And the other page shows the complete details of that package when clicked.
[image: Package Details]

While showing the list of packages on the first page I don't need the complete 'Package' object. I just need a few pieces of data from that object like title, subtitle, price, number of days and nights, and image. The 'Package' object has much more fields of data than required to show the list, but this data will be required to show the package details when user clicks on a package from the list.

So my question is, should I fetch the complete list of 'Package' objects in one back-end API call or should I fetch a list of only necessary data in the first API call and when user clicks on a package I should get only that single 'Package' object?

In the first case, a huge chunk of data will be fetched from the server in just one API call. In the second case, there will be 2 Back-end API calls, Minimal data which is sufficient for rendering the list will be fetched in the first API call and in the second API call a single package object will be fetched when user clicks on a specific package of the list.

Which will be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion, You should take all data in list API with Main image and Thumbnail  image so, On the list display Thumbnail image and the details display main image. As per talking about performance wise, Application that has less API call It will be best for user usage. And also your App is not e-commercial app so your details page has not much data required.